# Search an ArrayList for a particular Object

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I have a class called `Person`. It has the following `attributes`; It has 2 attributes, `ID`, and `Telephone`. 1 person can have many telephones, so you may see people with multiple ID's below.

```
public ArrayList<Person> all(){

    p = new ArrayList<Person>();
    p.add(new Person(1,266763));
    p.add(new Person(1, 358643));
    p.add(new Person(2, 4667763));

    return p; 
}
```

There's another class called `PersonDB`. and it will have a method called, `findPersonWithTheTelephoneNumber(int telephone)`.

```
public void findPersonWithTheTelephoneNumber(int telephone) {
   Person pp = new Person();
   ArrayList<Person> personList = pp.all();

   // Now i want to find the Person object that will match the telephone number of these list of personList.


}
```

The personList, has 3-4 Person objects. I need to search the PersonArrayList and find the object that will match the Person object. How can i get this done ?

Note: i tried `personList.contains()`. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i tried personList.contains()

Make sure you override `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()` for Person class. But you have to have equality check on telephone number assuming telephone number unique. This would not be a solution but a workaround. Use bellum's answer. Mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I don't like this solutions as this would mean two `Person`s are equal if they have the same phone number (regardless their ID).

Comment: In the OP's example I don't think `person.id` is available, so there's no way to do an equality test.  Unless phone numbers are unique to people and the only person attribute used to check equality is the phone number.

Comment: Can you show me an example how to achieve this. i am a bit new

Comment: Yes but if you implement `hashCode` and `equals` as you mentioned you can only check the phone number only then `contains(phonNumber)` will work. I'm waiting for your example, maybe I get something wrong.

Comment: @sharonHwk : I will give you example, can you post your Person class?

Comment: @user714965 : yes you are right, we will have to have equality on phone number

Answer (score 3):

```
//...
Person foundPerson = null;
for (Person p : personList){
    if (p.getTelephone() == telephone){
         foundPerson = p; //or simply return it from there
         break;
    }
}
```

For implementing `hashCode` and `equals` you can observe [this tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=586).

Comment: This is the right answer, but you may want to consider building a hash mapping phone numbers to people if you care about performance.  Otherwise it's going to iterate through the list every time.  I'd also suggest breaking out of the loop as soon as a person is found, if you iterate.

Comment: What is the most efficient out of the 2 ? is it iterating or using hasCode/equals ?

Comment: @sharonHwk On long run implementing `hashCode/equals` and using methods like `get/contains` is more efficient then traversing through list every time.

Comment: @sharonHwk the fastest will be a `Map<PhoneNumber, Person>`. Implementing hashCode and equals here is a bad hack, because this would mean, that two `Person`s are equal if their phone number are equal. Their ID is not considered then. Works but is bad design.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why are you not having a `List<Integer>` for storing all your `telephoneNumbers` for a particular person. That way, you won't have to create a separate `Person` instance for each `telephoneNumber` for the same `personId`, which simply makes no sense.

You can change your attributes of Person class to: -

```
private int id;
private List<Integer> telephoneNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And then have a list of Person, as you are having.

To find a `Person` with a particular telephoneNumber, you need to iterate through your `List<Person>`.

```
for (Person person: personList) {
    if (person.getTelephoneNumbers().contains(telephone)) {
        return person;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array, check the persons one by one for phone number, and when you get to the one you need just assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop to iterate through the list. In the body of the loop, check if the telephone number of the person in the list is the telephone number you're looking for. If yes, then return the person.

See [The `for` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions, define two persons as equal by their phone number but what if two persons that live in the same house and / or have the same phone number are added to the list? Which one is the correct one?.

Before rushing to find the person, you have to define a way to determine if two persons are, indeed, equal without ambiguous results. Unless you restrict the creation of persons based on that very phone number by making it unique (you do not clarify this in your question, so I assume there is no such restriction), the result of the search is undefined.

You're using an `ArrayList` so you can't guarantee even a result by insertion order.

I suggest you base the equality test in a person's `ID` instead of its phone. To prevent the modification of `id`'s just define a getter for it and do not define a `setId` method at all. Then, you can redefine `equals` (and `hashcode` if you feel like it) based on `id`.